# I'm not able to set a padding-right to the main area

Tags: css, html, margin, padding

If you zoom in with your browser [here](http://goo.gl/bm85n) you can notice that there's only a padding-left, nothing at the right margin (so the div "touches" the end of the screen). I can't seem to fix this. I tried applying a padding-right:2em to both body, #page.. without any luck!

Do you have a solution..?

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in? And what element on the page are you concerned about?

Comment: I forgot to post the image:
http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/3239/rightmargin.png

When you are on iPhone for example (or zooming with browsers) you see there's no space between the right margin and the end of the screen (instead there is at the left).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to add an extra conainer block which will hold your page content. You can try something like this:

```
<div id="layout">
    <div id="page">
        <!-- Your page content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

After the new structure is built, the resulting #layout div should have the padding of the body element and some of the #page styles:

```
#layout {
    min-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2em;
}
```

If you don't want to change the current HTML structure, there is also a 'dirty' trick you can try: add a gray border to the '#page' div:

```
#page { 
    border: 2em solid #e2e2e2; 
}
```

But be careful when you use something like this because there might be unwanted side effects.

As a final note, you might want to move the main CSS file after the rest of the style sheets. Otherwise you will end up with some of your styles overriden by the subsequent files.

Comment: The problem with both methods is that a padding is already present at the left. If I add a padding/border 2em it will add another 2em to the left. And if I only add it to the right #layout/#page isn't center aligned anymore..

Comment: Ok, fixed with a body {padding:0}

Comment: You take out the padding style from the body and add it to the '#layout'. Even more, you can enforce the body to have padding: 0; as you correctly mentioned above.